# Using optional parameter in method calling (Angular 6+) or Method overloading in Angular 6+

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to implement method overloading in my component. I found a previous answer about it here - to use the "?" operator like this :

```
myFunction(param1, param2?, param3?) {}
```

In my case I want to use it with a viewchild `TemplateRef` reference :

```
generate_ticket(templateA?: TemplateRef<any>, templateB?: TemplateRef<any>) {}
```

See here, I need to pass my desired `TemplateRef` from my `.html` file. So, both the parameters are needed to be optional. But, if I try it like above it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone tell me how to make this work? If you need any additional info, please let me know. TIA !

Comment: "if I try it like above it doesn't seem to work." what do you mean by this? isn't the code executing? have you tried console.log at the start of the function to see if he is even going into the function? is an error thrown?

Comment: The `TemplateRef` was used for showing a modal-popup. To answer your questions yeah, the code is executing fine, there is no error, the function is getting access too. But the modal is't properly showing. I only get the faded area of the Modal in the screen, nothing else.

Comment: Can you provide example screenshots of your problem? It seams like optional parameter are not your problem. You could console.log the optional parameters to look if the object appears like you expect them to do.

Comment: I checked consoling the results of `templateA`, with the `?` sign , it consoles `undedfined`. But in general case it consoles the usual result.

Comment: An old javascript trick is to console log out the arguments object.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: share you code somewhere !